# Как запустить java-файл с помощью javac

Tags: java, javac

Как запустить java-файл без среды разработки? Выдает ошибку:

> "javac" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

мой путь JDK:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\
```

В Path такая абракадабра:

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>   C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;с:%JAVA_HOME%\bin;\Program Files\Skype\Phone\

Как всё это настроить, и что это за наука - где учиться?

Comment: Поправте пунктуацию, не совсем понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: добавьте ``c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\`` в Path

Comment: Пишем в консоли путь bin папке, далее добавляем имя javac. Далее указываем опции для javac (например -cp - "class path" - для указания пути к классам), далее - компиллируемый класс (полный путь к .java файлу). Опция -d - "directory" - задаст путь к директорию, куда будут сложены скомпиллированные .class файлы.
Ну а далее - java [ИмяСкомпиллированногоФайла]. И программа запустится.

Comment: А в   cmd.exe  должен какой адрес быть у меня почемуто  адрес среды разработки IDEA

Comment: Как правильно добавить    c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\     в Path     что там за абракадабра   как с этим разобраться

Comment: А в консоли то как написать у меня почемуто адрес IDEA

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в конец Path:

> ;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\

и перезагрузите компьютер

Пример: 
C:\greetings\Hello.java

```
package greetings;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

C:>javac greetings\Hello.java
 
C:>dir greetings /B
 
Hello.class
 
Hello.java
 
C:>java greetings.Hello World Universe Everyone
 
Hello World
 
Hello Universe
 
Hello Everyone

https://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Я добавил адрес jdk в конец Path выдает ошибку "javac" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Comment: А по самому пути что-нибудь существует?

Comment: Да jdk      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: скиньте все что написано в Path с добавленным jdk.
Попробуйте написать в консоль
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe"